# One GridView and many LinkButtons (asp .net WebForms)

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, webforms

I have a GridView and dynamically added LinkButton in GridView cell:

```
protected void TestGrid_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            foreach (var l in links)
            {
               e.Row.Cells[6].Controls.Add(l.button);
               PostBackTrigger trigger = new PostBackTrigger();
               trigger.ControlID = l.button.ID;
               UpPanel.Triggers.Add(trigger);
            }
        }
 }
```

Links are added, its ok, but clicking on link, GridView refreshes and links disappears. When I delete this condition from page_load function, I have a problem with page index changing event - GridView does not refresh:

```
if (!IsPostBack)
{
    TestGrid.DataBind();
}
```

What can I do to stop links disappearing and keep page index functional? And is there a better way to add many LinkButtons in one GridView cell? Thank you!

Comment: Why not place the buttons in the GridView already? Because if that is not an option, using dynamic controls and enable paging without double hitting the database can become complex.

Comment: Because i don't know how many LinkButtons will be, their count is dinamic too. And this is the big problem.

Comment: Then you have to remove the IspostBack check. And then after setting the PageIndex, call DataBind again (double hit). That way it works both with dynamic controls and paging.

Comment: According to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279455/gridview-rowdatabound-doesnt-fire-on-postback the RowDataBound event will only fire during a postback when the grid data has changed.

To help suggest a workaround, can you define what action your links should be performing during the postback?